# What is the correct multiple regression method to answer my hypotheses?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, feature-selection, aic

I have a dataset in which I'm looking to explore the relationships between nine input variables (X1 - X9) and five outputs (Y1 - Y5). For each output, I have a hypothesis based on the previous literature relating to some combination of the inputs, or none of the inputs at all, e.g.

H1: X1-X6 will predict Y1
H2: X5, X6 and X7 will predict Y2
H3: X2, X4, X8 and X9 will predict Y3
H4: None of the inputs will predict Y4
H5: None of the inputs will predict Y5

I'm currently considering three regression procedures I could use to explore these hypotheses:

1. **Forced entry**. Construct a model for each output including all potential predictors. From the coefficients table, report the predictors which are significant at the P<0.05 level. Maybe re-run the regression, dropping all the non-significant predictors, and then report the adjusted r-squared value.
2. **Stepwise**. Construct a model for each output including all potential predictors, but specify the stepwise procedure. Report all of the (significant) predictors retained in the final model, along with the adjusted r-squared value.
3. **All-possible-subsets**. Use the all-possible-subsets approach within SPSS to identify the model with the lowest AIC. Report all of the predictors in the identified model OR report only the predictors which are significant at the P<0.05 level, along with the adjusted r-squared value.

Can anybody help me to work out which of these (if any) is the most appropriate approach? Many thanks in advance

Comment: if you already have hypothesis, why do you need to run all these feature selection procedures?

Comment: It's a relatively undeveloped area of research, so while there's some research literature backing up my hypotheses, many of the potential relationships between the variables just haven't been explored previously. For example, let's say that X9 is age - there's no prior evidence to suggest that age will influence Y1, but maybe it's worth testing that anyway seeing as we have the data. Is that a valid approach?